# Crontab is not setup after a deployment with rake task and whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, ruby-on-rails-6, whenever, clever-cloud

I use the `gem whenever` to manage cron task throught my rails 6.0 app. the rake task that manage Cron task is called during the deployment but crontab schedule is empty after deployment.

config/schedule.rb

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb'

 env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
 set :output, "log/cron_log.log"
 set :runner_command, "rails runner"

  set :chronic_options, hours24: true

every 1.day, at: ['5:01', '11:01', '17:01','23:01'] do
  runner "Task1"
end

every 1.hours do
  runner "Task2"
end
```

i created a rake task in `lib/tasks/start.rake`

```
desc 'launch cron task'
task :start_whenever do
  puts 'rake start_whenever'
  sh 'whenever'
  sh 'bundle exec whenever --update-crontab'
  puts **'cron activate'**
end
```

When i launch the rake task manually `bundle exec rake start_whenever` after a deploy, it work perfectly

but i want this task be runned automatically after each deploy. so i tried 2 solutions:

first, as suggested by my hosting service, i call rack task in a configuration file.

https://www.clever-cloud.com/doc/getting-started/by-language/ruby/
clevercloud/ruby.json

```
{
  "deploy": {
    "rakegoals": ["assets:precompile", "db:migrate", "start_whenever"]
  }
}
```

second, i call the raketask from the migration

```
class LaunchWhenever < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    Rake::Task['start_whenever'].invoke
  end
end
```

Both results are the same. the rake task `start_whenever` is called during the deployment but the crontab is not setup.

```
## [message] Above is your schedule file converted to cron syntax; your crontab file was not updated.
2021-07-12T09:00:57.352Z: ## [message] Run `whenever --help' for more options.
2021-07-12T09:00:57.352Z: bundle exec whenever --update-crontab
2021-07-12T09:00:57.353Z: [write] crontab file updated
2021-07-12T09:00:57.353Z: **cron activate**
2021-07-12T09:00:57.353Z: Creating build cache archive
2021-07-12T09:01:00.700Z: build cache archive successfully created
2021-07-12T09:01:00.700Z: **No cron to setup**
```

the command line `crontab -l` gives `no crontab for bas`

Thanks for any help!

environnement

```
Rails version             6.0.3.4
Ruby version              ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x86_64-linux]
RubyGems version          3.0.3
Rack version              2.2.3
JavaScript Runtime        Node.js (V8)
```

Comment: Another way to go is to use the gem "arask". It works without any external setup.

Comment: Thanks! i will take a look on a next project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gem `whenever` wont be able to update crontab itself. You should use Clever Cloud's [CRON](https://www.clever-cloud.com/doc/administrate/cron/) system to execute your rake tasks periodically.

I am working at Clever Cloud.